# I haven't offered you at least a drink

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

> I haven't offered you at least a drink.

Have I used *at least* correctly here? Are there rules to how an expression like *at least* is used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more at home on ELL.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence does not sound correct.

I think you mean to say that

**Affirmative sentence**

> Let me offer you a drink at least.

Or you can use *at least* at the beginning which goes like this

> At least, let me offer you a drink.

**Negative sentence**

> I haven't even offered you a drink.

Answer (score 0):

Your modifier, "at least" is misplaced, making it plausible to assume that of all the people in the room, at least you should have been offered a drink. Place your modifiers as close to that being modified (in this case the verb as opposed to the pronoun).

**I haven't, at least, offered you a drink.** (commas are certainly debatable)

In this sentence, "at least" is not particularly useful.

More useful here (but not really):

**You could have, at least, offered him a drink.**

Comment: I would phrase that last example as _You could at least have offered him a drink_.

Comment: @oerkelens: Agreed.

Comment: It's not the placement that's wrong, it's the use of *at least* in a negative sentence.